# My calculator cannot calculate properly java

Tags: java, swing, calculator

Hi i'm a young programmer and i need some help with my calculator. Every time I try to get it too calculate it keeps giving me the wrong answer for example 2+2 will equal -2. Can someone please help me. By the way i'm learning code from a book so someone might recognize some of the code.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
public class CalculationEngine implements ActionListener{

String number1, number2, abplus,abminus,abEquals1;
double a,b,a2,b2;
int rounding,rounding2;


//Don't change this!
Calculator c2;
//Or this.
CalculationEngine(Calculator c2){
    //This statement allows this class to "communicate" with the other class
    this.c2=c2;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    JButton getbutton=(JButton) e.getSource();

    String getbuttonlabel= getbutton.getText();
    String buttonsfieldtext=c2.getbuttonsfield();

    c2.setbuttonsfieldtext(buttonsfieldtext+getbuttonlabel);

    number1=buttonsfieldtext;
    number2=buttonsfieldtext;

    try{
        if(getbuttonlabel.equals("+")){
            a=Double.parseDouble(number1);
            c2.setbuttonsfieldtext("");
        }else if (getbuttonlabel.equals("=")){
            b=Double.parseDouble(number2);
            rounding= (int) Math.round(a+b);
            abplus=String.valueOf(rounding);
            c2.setbuttonsfieldtext(abplus);

        }

    }catch(NumberFormatException e1){
        System.out.println("There was an error in your typing "+e1.getMessage());
        c2.setbuttonsfieldtext("");
    }

    try{
        if(getbuttonlabel.equals("-")){
            String number3=buttonsfieldtext;
            a2=Double.parseDouble(number3);
            c2.setbuttonsfieldtext("");
        }else if (getbuttonlabel.equals("=")){
            String number4=buttonsfieldtext;
            b2=Double.parseDouble(number4);
            rounding2= (int) Math.round(a2-b2);
            abminus=String.valueOf(rounding2);
            c2.setbuttonsfieldtext(abminus);

        }

    }catch(NumberFormatException e1){
        System.out.println("There was an error in your typing "+e1.getMessage());
        c2.setbuttonsfieldtext("");
    }




}
```

}

Comment: You should expand a bit on "keeps giving me the wrong answer". What is your test data? What did you expect? What did you actually get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this line,

```
int rounding= (int) Math.round(a+b);
```

You are setting the value of rounding, before you have set the new a and b values. You need to call this **after** you set the new a and b values, or the value of rounding will not be updated correctly.

You also have two blocks that start : `else if (getbuttonlabel.equals("="))`. *Both* of these blocks are executed each time that getbuttonlabel is equal to "=", so if you are trying to add two numbers, the second block will always overwrite the results of the first, so what happens is that the two numbers are added in the first block, then in the second "=" block, that sum of the two numbers get subtracted from the first number, which gives you a negative value of the second number as your result.

To fix this without completely changing the design of your program, you could add a variable in the class (not the function) that stores whether the last operation was a + or -. Then in the function, check this before you process the "=" block. That way only the correct "=" block will get run when the function is called.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't really help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by didnt help. Did it alter the result at all when you corrected the code? It should have done. Can you please  update your post to show what it looks like now?

Comment: you now have another mistake, setting the value of abplus before you set the value of rounding: `abplus=String.valueOf(rounding);
            rounding= (int) Math.round(a+b);` these two statements should be the other way around. Could you fix this, then please provide some simple examples of data that you put in, and what results you get out.

Comment: Alright I changed the order of things and I tried to do some math, but the calculator appears to take the value of the second number I input and change it to negative. examples: 2+2= -2, 3+4= -4, 1+5= -5, 33+55= -55

Comment: You have two blocks that start : `else if (getbuttonlabel.equals("="))`. _Both_ of these blocks are executed each time that getbuttonlabel is equal to "=", so if you are trying to add two numbers, the second block will always overwrite the results of the first, so what happens is that the two numbers are added in the first block, then in the second "=" block, that sum of the two numbers get subtracted from the first number, which gives you a negative value of the second number as your result.

Comment: Without completely changing the design of your program, you could add a variable in the class (not the function) that stores whether the last operation was a + or -. Then in the function, check this before you process the "=" block. That way only the correct "=" block will get run when the function is called.

Comment: Would you mind marking the answer as accepted if it helped solve your problem? I have updated the answer according to our comments.